# Testing MFA using sandbox account

Tags: plaid

I'm having problem testing MFA using the sandbox environment. Posting to the connect/step endpoint is returning 401:

```
curl -X POST https://tartan.plaid.com/connect/step -d client_id=test_id -d secret=test_secret -d access_token="test" -d mfa="tomato"
{
  "code": 1108,
  "message": "invalid type",
  "resolve": "This institution is not currently supported."
}
```

Is it possible to test MFA using the sandbox environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly set the type in sandbox mode.

So add `-d type=whatever_institution` to your curl.

Consider

[image: https://cl.ly/image/0L1e3Z0v092G/Image%202014-11-20%20at%2010.55.24%20PM.png]

as the beginning of the mfa process and then

[image: https://cl.ly/image/002943322608/Image%202014-11-20%20at%2010.57.31%20PM.png]

as the next step in the sequence.